# How to return a json array from a query?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

In a postgres 10 database, there are three tables:

main:

```
id | name
-----------
1  | first
2  | second
3  | third
…
```

substances

```
id  | name
----------------------
1   | gold
2   | silver
3   | aluminum
…
```

link

```
id  | id_main  | id_substance
---------------------------------
1   | 1        | 1
2   | 1        | 2
3   | 1        | 3
4   | 2        | 1
5   | 3        | 2
6   | 3        | 3
```

**How to make query to return a json object like this?**

```
[
  {
    "name": "first",
    "substances": ["gold", "silver", "aluminum"]
  },
  {
    "name": "second",
    "substances": ["gold"]
   },
   {
    "name": "third",
    "substances": ["silver", "aluminum"]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the aggregate function [`jsonb_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) twice to build json arrays on two levels:

```
select jsonb_agg(a_row)
from (
    select 
        jsonb_build_object(
            'name', main_name, 
            'substances', jsonb_agg(substances_name)
        ) as a_row
    from (
        select m.name as main_name, s.name as substances_name
        from link l
        left join main m on id_main = m.id
        left join substances s on id_substances = s.id
        ) s
    group by main_name
    ) s;
```

The (formatted) result:

```
[
    {
        "name": "first",
        "substances": ["gold", "silver", "aluminum"]
    },
    {
        "name": "third",
        "substances": ["silver", "aluminum"]
    },
    {
        "name": "second",
        "substances": ["gold"]
    }
]
```